# Add exchange account in Android 4.1.2

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, exchange

I have just bought three cheap china-pads and on all of them the OS registers as 4.1.2. On two of them, it says "build version" or something like that v 1.6rc1 but on the third it says 1.5.

The difference between them is that on the 1.5 pad, the option to add an Exchange account is present, but is missing on the other two.

Is there a way to fix this? I have tried a couple of apps, but would really like to integrate my work Exchange account.

Answer (score 0):

Open the email app, type in the login credentials, go to manual setup and follow these settings [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/settings-for-pop-and-imap-access-HA102908389.aspx)

[image]

I personally use POP3 for my exchange account.